# I can't choose to open with Java 8. It goes to Internet Explorer and I get stuck in a loop. What do I do?

Tags: path, javac

I have installed Java 8 JDK and JRE, and when I type javac into cmd, everything seems fine. However, when I download a .jar, for example Optifine, I have no option to open with Java. The icon of the .jar is Internet Explorer. When I double-click on the Optifine .jar, I am brought to a "View and track your downloads" window, where I then get stuck in a "Save" and "Open" loop. What can I do to actually see Java as an option to open with? Sidenote: if anyone does reply, please use simpler coding language, as my knowledge only comes from hours of research on how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of Windows you are using so I can provide detailed step by step guide. .jar files can be opened with Java and compression/decompression utilities. In general, you can change the default programs in control panel and associate .jar file with a specific program you want.
Note: As an irrelevant point in order to use Optifine.jar for Minecraft modding you do not need to open it.